# Grabbing a part of a string using regex in python 3.x

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, findall

So what i am trying to do is to have an input field named a. Then have a line of regex which checks a for 'i am (something)' (note something could be a chain of words.) and then prints How long have you been (something)?

This is my code so far:

```
if re.findall(r"i am", a):
    print('How long have you been {}'.format(re.findall(r"i am", a)))
```

But this returns me a list of [i, am] not the (something). How do i get it to return me (something?)

Thanks,

A n00b at Python

Comment: in "i am noviceprogrammer" you want to print "noviceprogrammer" not "(noviceprogrammer)" isnt it ?

Comment: Show some sample `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "I am a programmer"
>>> reg = re.compile(r'I am (.*?)$')
>>> print('How long have you been {}'.format(*reg.findall(a)))
How long have you been a programmer
```

`r'I am (.*?)$'` matches `I am` and then everything else to the end of the string.

---

To match one word after, you can do:

```
>>> a = "I am an apple"
>>> reg = re.compile(r'I am (\w+).*?$')
>>> print('How long have you been {}'.format(*reg.findall(a)))
How long have you been an
```

Comment: Wait one more thing @Haidro This matches all the words after i am. How do i get it to match just 1?

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer I added a solution

Comment: may be by changing just `(.*?)` by `\w+` but this time it will return "a" and not "programmer"

Comment: @FoxMaSk He only wants the word after.

Answer (score 0):

may be just a simple solution avoiding a weigth and cost regexp

```
>>> a = "i am foxmask"
>>> print a[5:]
foxmask
```

Comment: Seems like the OP wants to use regular expressions

Comment: Yes I know but it may be possible to see an alternative of the "re" module for this simple question

Comment: @FoxMaSk well i need regex because i am could be anywhere in a line not just at the start.

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer Can't with Slice Notation without determining the length of the word